# How to keep track of screens in Google Analytics?

Tags: react-native, google-analytics

I want to keep track of all screens that I visited previously, but in react-native when I used firebase.analytics.logScreenView() it is only keeping track of current and previous screen. How to keep track of all screens then?

I used firebase.analytics.logScreenView() it is only keeping track of current and previous screen. How to keep track of all screens then?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you actually want to do. However, it seems extremely unlikely that tracking all previous pages in current page would ever be feasible. Let's start from basics, just to make sure you have them covered.

When you send current and last page on every page, it becomes completely enough to get all pages that you visited. With that pageview hit, the SDK also sends your unique client id, your session id and other information needed to bind your older screen views and events to current.

You don't use Firebase to pull this data, however. Firebase reporting interface is awful. What you want to do is [connect](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9289234?hl=en) your firebase to a GA4 property. After it, you can explore your data fully in GA4. Use Explorer. See how you can now pull dimensions and metrics into there and generate all the relevant reports.

From there, you won't be able to actually go too deep, however. It's not meant to explore distinct users and sessions. However, the data for this is still there, so you can [export](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9823238?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) your GA4 data to BQ where you will see your data in a table. You would be able to use SQL to pull whatever you need. From there, you can easily pull all page views for a user or even a session ordered by hit timestamp and many other goodies.

You still want to track past page names in every pageview? Well, you can make a static (or global) variable where you would store them. Then you concatenate new page names to it every time a page is hit. You also pass that string as a custom event property. You will have to register that property as a custom dimension for it to pop in Firebase/GA4.

There's a limitation to the max length of an event property. You can either send page ids or build a system out of multiple event properties to store the same dimension.

This is an extremely patchy and hacky implementation though, I would advise against trying to pass visited page names with each page.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! What I want to do is to create a folder structure in google analytics, like if I click on a screen name then I will get to know all screen names and event names that are called inside that screen.

Comment: Can you please help me how can I do that? @BNazaruk

Comment: screen names can't be called inside one screen. As for events, yes, you can just make pull the page name and the event name dimensions in one report in the Explorer, using hit as a metric and you will get all page names with associated events. Or you can just use the filter function in the Explorer and set specific page name, pulling all events that fire there as a dimension, having the hit as a metric.